# Automatically save Word document as PDF at a specific time?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm a teacher and I have a word document where I save answers to a worksheet we do in class. To share the latest answers with the class, I save this docx as a PDF, and then a link to this PDF file is shared to the class via Google Drive. So every time I update the docx, I can save as PDF and the class will see the updated PDF file with the same Google Drive link every time.

I want to share the latest worksheet answers with my class, but not until after the class ends. I often save the docx file with the answers before class, but then I have to wait until after class to reopen the docx and save as PDF.

Is there a way I can automate this process? Is there a way I can tell word to save the file as a PDF (and confirm that I want to overwrite the existing PDF file with the same name) at a specific time of day?

Comment: Perhaps someone with VB Script expertise can use the timer function to print (to PDF) at an interval? BTW, expect that MS Word will freeze while printing.